# Solving differential equation using an integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is as follows: $$(\cos(x)e^x+xy+4y^2-y)dx+(-x-8y)dy=0$$

I have worked out that it isn't exact and I have worked out the integrating factor to be $e^x$

I have then multiplied the original equation by $e^x$ to get 
$$(\cos (x)e^{2x}+xye^x+4y^2e^x-ye^x)dx+(-xe^x-8ye^x)dy=0$$

I am stuck trying to find the solution in terms of $f(x,y)=c$

Comment: Do you mean $\cos(xe^x)$ or $\cos(x)e^x$?

Comment: @callculus its $e^x \cos x$

Comment: Look at the line where OP multiplied the DE with integrating factor @callculus

Comment: @LostInSpace Good catch.

Comment: lol @callculus Thank you .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let it be $Mdx+Ndy=0, M=\cos x e^x+xy+4y^2-y, N=-x-8y$ 
so Here $$\frac {\partial M}{\partial y}=x+8y-1, \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=-1=$$
Integrating factor $$\mu(x)= \exp ~[\int \frac{[\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}] dx}{N}] =e^{-x}$$
So the soluytion of the ODE can be written as
$$\int e^{-x} (\cos x e^x+xy+4y^2-y) dx \text{[treat $y$ as constant]}+ \int 0 dy=C$$
$$\implies \sin x-e^{-x}y(x+4y)=C$$

Comment: Thankyou, I didn't realise I had miscalculated my integrating factor. This has helped me a lot

Answer (score 3):

$$(\cos xe^x+xy+4y^2-y)dx+(-x-8y)dy=0$$
Rearrange some terms:
$$\cos xe^xdx-(d(xy)-xydx)+(4y^2dx-8ydy)=0$$
Factor integrating is $e^{-x}$ not $e^x$:
$$\cos xdx-d(e^{-x}xy)-e^{-x}(-4y^2dx+8ydy)=0$$
$$\cos xdx-d(e^{-x}xy)-4d(e^{-x}y^2)=0$$
Integrate.
$$\sin x-e^{-x}xy-4e^{-x}y^2=C$$